# Find rows within date range for multiple dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of dates, and I want to find any rows where a range would include them.

Currently it works well with one,

```
select * from holiday where startDate <= '2022-08-05' and endDate >= '2022-08-05';
```

However I want to perform this on **multiple dates** like:

```
'2022-08-01', '2022-08-05', '2022-08-20', '2022-09-02'
```

This could be done with multiple `or` queries,

```
select * from holiday where 
(startDate <= '2022-08-01' and endDate >= '2022-08-01'
or startDate <= '2022-08-05' and endDate >= '2022-08-05'
or startDate <= '2022-08-20' and endDate >= '2022-08-20'
or startDate <= '2022-09-02' and endDate >= '2022-09-02')
```

or joining a temp table:

```
select * from holiday where 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(date '2022-08-01'), ('2022-08-05'), ('2022-08-20'), ('2022-09-02')) g(day)
where startDate <= g.day and endDate >= g.day
```

However I was trying to find another way so that it can handle a dynamic set of dates without creating a temp table.
The `OVERLAPS` operator is only useful for ranges, not multiple dates.

Comment: Add the dates to a table and join?  Maybe you can show some sample data here.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, edited to add examples and what I've tried. I was looking for a way without a temp table.

Comment: In your example, `startDate` and `endDate` have the same value, in the real use case is it also like that?